# How do I force execution of previously injected scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a DIV that I inject 4 or 5 different SCRIPT elements that are dynamically created.  The scripts execute at the time of injection.  Events are eventually raised causing need to execute any SCRIPTs that exist within the DIV again.

```
<DIV id="divWrapper">
    <script id="scr1">...</script>
    <script id="scr2">...</script>
    <script id="scr3">...</script>
    <script id="scr4">...</script>
</DIV>
```

I have forced divWrapper to re-render, but that does not cause the injected scripts to execute again.

TY for your time.

Comment: It kinda depends what the scripts do (and to a lesser extent, how they are created). Why have multiple scripts rather that one, for instance?

Comment: Why don't you have the `script`s define unique functions that you can call again?

Comment: My scripts support 3rd party business objects we use on our intranet.  They are generated and added to the parent container of the object.  Some of these scripts handle the formatting of the object.  When the user resizes the window, I need to call these scripts to format the 3rd party object.  I cannot modify or move these scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option, I think, is to have your scripts define unique functions that can be called later.

If you don't want to have to give these functions all unique names, you can structure your scripts like so:

- at global initialization (before scripts are loaded) create an empty global array
- have each dynamically loaded script define a function containing all the script code, call it, and append the new function to the global array
- call every function in the global array when your events arrive

Comment: My scripts support 3rd party business objects we use on our intranet. They are generated and added to the parent container of the object at run time by the objects. Some of these scripts handle the formatting of the object. When the user resizes the window, I need to call these scripts to format the 3rd party object. I cannot modify or move these scripts.

Comment: Do you know if these scripts define any functions you could call?

Comment: Yes.  Part of my problem is that the number of script tags vary depending on user settings.  I cannot count on any of them being there every time.  So I was just hoping to figure out how to re-execute every script tag that may be present.  TY for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do two things:

- Wrap them in a function and when you rerender divs, also call them by calling those functions.
- or Just use `eval()`

Comment: No, don't just use `eval`. It's evil and slow.

Comment: It's not a matter of if I "want to"; it's a matter of "that's bad advice".

Comment: hmm maybe...sometimes it's the only way. But most of time it's not. Especially when its coming form user. Did you notice this 'bad adivce' was only after 'good advice'.